# Android custom IME for specific InputType

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, android-inputtype

I am currently developing an IME which generate me a dynamic password based on my input.
I used the sample SoftKeyboard in order to undertake this project.

When I need to type a password, I just need to change the Input Method and for now, it seems to be ok.

My question is quite simple. Is there a way to allow this IME only when the InputType is a  password type like (InputType = TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD) 
Or would there be a method to specify a specific keyboard (in this case my IME) when InputType is a password type?

Thank you !

Comment: please post an SSCCE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.  There's 2 things that control the IME.  First, the user sets a single default IME for the phone.  There is no way to split this up by type or anything else.  Second, the app can request a specific IME for a text field.  Usually this is done only if the app itself is providing that IME.  There is no way for a keyboard to make itself the default, or for it to override the default for a type.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer Gabe Sechan !
I think I will replace all keys (execpt space) by a "delete" or anything else if the inputType is not a password.

Comment: @GabeSechan What code would the app use to request a specific IME for an EditText?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering You use tha android:inputMethod xml oarameter, and pass it the fully qualified class name you want to use.  This should only be used (and is only assured to work) for an IME that's part of your app.  It should not be used to force a specific keyboard app to be used, and even if that app is installed probably won't work for that.

Comment: @GabeSechan `android:inputMethod` is now deprecated. I tried it anyway, but end up with **ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MyCustomIME" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]**. I've added `-keep class com.example.MyCustomIME {*;}` to my proguard-rules.pro file, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: I've posted a new question here if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400635/how-to-use-androidinputtype-on-an-edittext-to-specify-my-custom-ime

Comment: @ban-geoengineering I'm not sure why you think that, its not listed as deprecated in the documentation.  ANd using inputType like you're trying will never work, inputType is a flag field of the type that will be passed to the IME-  inputMethod is the ONLY method of doing this.

Comment: @GabeSechan It's not documented here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputMethod  But it is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputMethod . Android Studio (everything up-to-date) appears to be going with the latter.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering I'd point out that deprecated doesn't mean gone or unusable.  But I'd trust the documentation on the widget before the R.attr.  And there is no other method of doing it (inputType is something totally different).

Comment: @GabeSechan OK, makes sense. Any idea how I can overcome the **ClassNotFoundException** error?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering I'd check that its properly registered as an IDE.  I'd also double check against proguard.  An easy way to do that is to try to access the class via reflection, if you can't its a problem.

Comment: @GabeSechan It's properly registered as an IME as it's available in the device's **Set up input methods** settings screen. I can also access the class via reflection. I've created a new question here with a bit more info if you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410616/classnotfoundexception-when-specifying-custom-ime-as-edittexts-androidinputmet