# How to use android:inputType on an EditText to specify my custom IME?

Tags: android, android-input-method, android-inputtype

My app includes a custom IME (that extends InputMethodService) and I would now like to specify this as the IME for all the EditTexts within my app.

Specifying an `android:inputMethod` for each EditText seems to be one old way of doing it, but `android:inputMethod` is now deprecated. The tooltip says to use `android:inputType` instead.

My existing code for one EditText is `android:inputType="numberPassword"`, but when I change this to `android:inputType=".MyCustomIME"` (or `android:inputType="com.example.MyCustomIME"`) I get this error in Android Studio:

> Cannot resolve flag.

So what is the correct way to specify my IME (either for a single EditText or for the whole app) - and without losing my existing `numberPassword` value (as this determines my IME subtype that will be used)?

My IME is defined in my manifest as:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyCustomIME"
    android:label="@string/my_keyboard"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.view.im"
        android:resource="@xml/keyboard_method" />
</service>
```

(NB - Using `android:name="com.example.MyCustomIME"` in the above `<service />` tag doesn't make any difference.)

Comment: Are you sure? You made a similar comment on another question/answer, but then corrected yourself. I can't find it now, but I did upvote your correction comment (a few minutes ago), so maybe you can find it?

Comment: "I did upvote your correction comment (a few minutes ago)" -- somebody downvoted the answer today, so I nuked it. I do agree with Mr. Sechan that `android:inputMethod` is not documented as deprecated. Personally, I wouldn't expect it to work reliably across device manufacturers. And, unless your IME handles every possible accessibility scenario, you may have some unhappy users. But, I deleted my previous comment here -- I should have done that after reviewing the downvote, but I forgot to, and I apologize for that.

Comment: OK, thanks - no worries. Seems like Android Studio is picking up this deprecation for some reason: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputMethod . I'll stick with trying to get inputMethod to work - as is being discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24791067/1617737 - if you've any ideas?

Comment: By the way, the app is for a single client who isn't happy with their device's default keyboard - hence my custom keyboard.

Comment: "Seems like Android Studio is picking up this deprecation for some reason" -- that's very strange. `TextView` doesn't show it as deprecated, and `android:inputType` isn't really a replacement. FWIW, I filed [a documentation issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146447055) about the discrepancy, though I have poor track record in getting anyone to look at this sort of thing.